# MySQL Stored Procedure - Can they hit databases with different ports?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, port, authentication

We had a stored procedure that hit a couple tables using the same login credentials.

Then suddenly, our Ops team tells me that they are switching one of the tables out and creating a tunnel for me to access it. Since the new connection is using a different port and different login credentials, it doesn't look like the stored procedure query will run correctly, as it was joining to the table that can only be accessed with the other login credentials and the other port.

Is it possible to have multi-port references in a MySQL stored procedure? Tried googling it but I couldn't find anything. The option I'm thinking about is having a python script to import the table into the original database that is referenced in the stored proc.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a [federated table](http://winashwin.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/mysql-federated-table/)? Generally `JOIN` operations have to be run against local tables only, and only those in the same database.

Comment: I am not using a federated table, but it did look like it might be a potential solution. Are you thinking that I should set up a federated table that references the new table via the new connection?

Comment: I'm thinking you're in for a world of hurt here if you can't keep the data you need to join against local, but the federated engine might be a way to bridge in remote data. I've never used it, but have considered it on a few occasions.

Comment: Yeah... I spoke with a few engineers on my team and they recommended getting Ops to get replication running locally vs. the way its set up now. They mentioned that federated tables are less than ideal.